# How to use JAlerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I am new to jQuery. Can some body tell me how to use JAlert in a project. Please help. thnx

ps

Hi I have used it in a netbeans project. But it doesnot work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jalert.js" ></script>
        <link href="jalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>
        function hello()
        {
           jAlert('Price should be blocks of 10 cents', 'FAILED', );
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="accounts" method="POST" action="test.jsp">
            <input type="button" name="clientAccount" value="click" onclick=hello()>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

can sombody tell me what the problem

Comment: Hi I have used it in a netbeans project. But it doesnot work

Comment: It seems it doesn't work this way. Please stretch your fingers a bit and try to look at an example.

Comment: add quotes around the `onclick=hello()`: `onclick="hello()"`.  
and what does the comma do after 'FAILED'?

Comment: oops sorry. I have faced to some syntax errors

Answer (score 5):

Go to the [jAlert demo](http://www.smooka.com/projects/jalert/) page and view the source code.

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/

But please first search for [jalert](http://www.google.com/search?q=jalert) in Google, if you can't find something, you can ask a question here.